# Location: Not working in firefox

Tags: php, firefox, backend

```
            if($query->num_rows===1)
            {
                    while($row = $query->fetch_object()){
                              $_SESSION['user'] = $row->user;
                              header('Location: http://www.URLISSECRETGOSH.com/index.php');
                             }
                    exit();
```

this works fine in chrome but I can't get it to work in firefox.

people say to move it to the top but that isn't really an option in this case.

Thank you,
lilsheep

Comment: Do you have any emission of whitespace or text above this line?

Comment: Sorry? Be more specific please! I have a newline above it

Comment: It has nothing to do with your problem but you really don't need a `while`-loop to fetch a single row.

Answer (score 0):

You should not have any charachter including new line above your location header. PHP should not print any char before setting header location to new location.

So if you have something like this

```
[newlinehere]
<?php

header('Location: http://www.URLISSECRETGOSH.com/index.php');
?>
```

it will not work. Your php tags and before php tags should not print any char.
Check for echo's in php, check new lines outside php tags. Nothing should be there and it will work then.

Comment: I have an if statement that echos characters but the else statement is what changes the location.

Comment: check for spaces, above php tags, make sure nothing is getting printed. Enable display_errors, it should show a warning about headers being sent. If you see it, you are missing a char or something before sending header to browser

Comment: what you have? do you have display_errors enabled? do you see warning? you've checked all spaces or any chars being printed before header location?